# Is Sentinel-1 GRD product Sigma0 or Gamma0 in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am using Sentinel-1 SAR GRD imagery with IW and EW swaths from ESA through Google Earth Engine.

- Is the pre-processed Sentinel-1 GRD product that I access through GEE is Sigma0 or Gamma0 or Beta0?
- Also how can I convert from Sigma0 to Gamma0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [As written in the first line of Sentinel-1 pre-processing description, Sentinel-1 GRD image collection represents sigma0 in dB.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/sentinel1#sentinel-1-preprocessing)
2. To convert sigma0 to gamma0, you can use the following trigonometric properties ([reference; slides 34-36](https://slidex.tips/downloadFile/terrasar-x-products-tips-and-tricks)):

sigma0 = beta0 * sin(theta) ... where beta0 is the square of raw digital number

gamma0 = beta0 * tan(theta)

thus,

gamma0 = sigma0/cos(theta)

You can implement the above expression in Earth Engine to obtain gamma0.

[Link to full code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/507931ed9f9ae32eb42192bea3f8b183)